# Shrinking or expanding object with retaining it's original shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

First of all, I am sorry, but I don't even know how to address this question properly. It's best illustrated by pictures below. So question is: Is there some way, in any graphic program (both vector, or raster), how to resize an object, so it keeps it's original position and retain it's original shape, meanwhile it can be fit inside or outside of itself's original? (I know it's hard to understand, but hopefully the picture will tell more)

Below are two images - one on the left was made by selection contraction, however, it doesn't solve the problem, cause some part of the object are lost, when shrinking too much. The one on the right was made by moving path points, which was done by moving all the points accordingly one by one... The goal is to achieve something like image on the right but of course by some automatic process.

Thank you

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is called an offset. Beyond offset there are many other possible ways to get the same effect. You need to page out to Illustrator to get this done. Straight on offset:

1. (optional) Expand text
2. Choose: **Effect → Path → Offset Path...** type in a suitable value, negative values eat into the shape.

Now the offset path is uniform offset, and you may want nonuniform offset. So you need to build it on your own. Do this:

1. assign a white stroke to your path that's twice as wide wide as your offset.
2. (optional)Expand the compound shape
3. adjust the path width selectively with the Width tool.
4. Expand.
5. Use Pathfinder to subtract the stroke from the shape.

Comment: Thx for reply. At least I know how to call it. Although your suggestion works, I need something more automated, so by few clicks it applies such a thing...

Comment: @salamun the computer can unfortunately not guess what you want. If you want a nonuniform solution your options are do manually or program the computer to do it for you. If you dont have it out of the box your out of luck with easy solutions.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. I was just hoping that there was some solution hidden in the menu of some program :)