# How can I do "Stroke Offset" in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke

In After Effects, when using a shape layer, I can add an offset to the stroke by applying a Trim Path.

I want to do something like this:

[image: I'm trying to make this]

I can convert the text into outlines, and create a stroke of it. Then the problem is, I want to push the stroke to the other side of the shape, the stroke is sticking to the starting path point.

How could I do that in Illustrator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrinking or expanding object with retaining it's original shape](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46303/shrinking-or-expanding-object-with-retaining-its-original-shape)

Comment: no @johnp, it's not what i want. i want to create a stroke of a shape, and then this problem come to me that i couldn't **move** the stroke to other part of the shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've converted the text to an outline, you could user object>path>offset path to add one or more offset versions (offset path will take positive and negative values) and then just chop the resulting paths up by deleting sections of them. It's a bit of work, but it will get you the effect that you are looking for.

Alternatively, if you don't want to create new paths, but want the strokes to be offset from the path (i.e. not where the path actually is) then you can do that with an art brush as follows:

1. Draw a series of offset lines or shapes, select them all and drag them to the `brushes` pallet:

[image]

2. Select `Art Brush` in the pop up that appears and hit `OK`.
3. Hit `OK` again, the defaults will be fine for the first try, but you may want to have a play with the settings later.
4. Create your shape or text (the text will have to be converted to paths) and click on the new brush that you have created to apply it. You will probably have to remove the fill colour. This is what you get...
   [image]

The 'size' of the brush can be adjusted by changing the stroke width. If you want a series of different or random looking styles like the example that you posted, just create more brushes with different arrangements of shapes or strokes.

Comment: No, it's not what i want. **It's not offset path, It's stroke offset.** I said to make it at the other side of the shape, not creating a new stroke.

Comment: I see what you mean, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Whoa, that's even better xD xD, btw is it fully editable if i've applied that art brush?

Comment: The shape remains editable, don't think there's a way to make it work with live text though.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use a dashed stroke:

[image: Dashed stroke]

You can apply multiple strokes with different offsets to a single live text object using the appearance panel.

You can add effects (such as Offset Path in this case, so that the strokes are outset from the text) to a specific stroke by selecting that stroke and using the "fx" button at the bottom of the appearance panel.

[image: Multiple offset dashed strokes]